# Store and Retrieve mp3 files in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, mp3, sql-server-ce, isolatedstorage

I'm new to windows phone development. I need to save and play audio files in my project. for that i need to store mp3 files into the database. I got idea from net, either we can store mp3 files directly to DB or store mp3 files to Isolatedstorage and store only URL in the database.

Now i was confused, we could be an easy way to achieve me expectation ? Suggest me which is one best? Also pls share some sample code....

Thanks
SheikAbdullah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the mp3's in Isolated Storage in the App/Shared/Media folder, then tell the Zune player to play them.

[How to: Play Background Audio for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202978%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Comment: i need to store more than 50 files, so i would like to save mp3 by sub folder.. shall i give path directly... how to do it...

Comment: Finally i stored music files to isolated storage and store path in db.. Thanks all..